# How can I use django with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, django

Can anyone provide me a sample project to understand.I want to use angularjs with django but not django-rest-framework?

Comment: Have you tried googling django+angular?

Comment: Doesn't [django-angular](https://github.com/jrief/django-angular/) work for you?

Comment: angular doesn't know about or care what backend language or framework you use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler way is to use [django-angular](https://github.com/jrief/django-angular) and you can see the code used in the demo at the bottom of the [demo](http://django-angular.awesto.com/classic_form/) page.

But aside for that, the best tutorial I've found out is this https://thinkster.io/django-angularjs-tutorial but it uses DRF.